# pytest configure upfront before running in parallel with xdist

Tags: pytest, xdist

I just started to use pytest in combination with xdist to run tests in parallel. I my contest.py I have a configure hook to create some test data direcories (with a time stamp) and files I need for my test run. All works fine until I use xdist. It looks like that pytest_configure is executed first and then again for each process again resulting in:

```
INTERNALERROR> OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/path/to/file'
```

And I end up with n+1 directories (a couple of seconds away).
Is there a way to configure the test run upfront before distributing?

Edit:
I might have found a solution to my problem [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1402). I still need to test it though.

Comment: I guess you should write your own lock mechanic.

Comment: Can you point me to an example how I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that solved my problem. I added the example code from the [link](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1402) how I implemented it. It is using a fixture to inject data to the `slaveinput` dict which is only written by the master process in `pytest_configure`.

```py
def pytest_configure(config):        
    if is_master(config):
        config.shared_directory = os.makedirs('/tests/runs/')  

def pytest_configure_node(self, node):
    """xdist hook"""
    node.slaveinput['shared_dir'] = node.config.shared_directory

@pytest.fixture
def shared_directory(request):
    if is_master(request.config):
        return request.config.shared_directory
    else:
        return request.config.slaveinput['shared_dir']

def is_master(config):
    """True if the code running the given pytest.config object is running in a xdist master
    node or not running xdist at all.
    """
    return not hasattr(config, 'slaveinput')
```